# Can I sum values within an entry in Elasticsearch and order by highest?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying out a bunch of different options for "fast query" of profile data. My first trial was I set up MemSQL and created a table like this:

```
username (PK) | attribute (PK) | value
```

Then if I have some data such as (but with many more attributes):

```
matt          | strength       | 32
matt          | dexterity      | 57
matt          | magic          | 13
...
fred          | strength       | 41
fred          | dexterity      | 66
fred          | magic          | 35
...
```

And then, if I want to get the user with the highest combination of strength and dexterity, I can do a simple query like:

```
SELECT username, sum(value) FROM profiles
where attribute in ('strength', 'dexterity')
group by username
order by sum(value) desc
```

This works perfectly, but is not quite as performant as I had hoped. So, since we already use elasticsearch in other parts of our company and it scales so well, and newer releases have the 'Aggregations' functionality, I thought maybe I could use that.

So I create a bunch of profiles:

```
    "_index": "profiles",
    "_type": "profile",
    "_id": "matt",
    "_source": {
       "strength": 73,
       "magic": 19,
       "dexterity": 34
    }
```

But looking at the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html, I can see how to sum the same field across lots of different profiles:

```
"aggs" : {
    "intraday_return" : { 
        "sum" : { 
            "field" : "strength" 
        }
    }
}
```

but how do I sum different fields within the same profile, and get the profile(s) with the highest score(s)? Do I do some kind of nesting, combining the 'max' function with the 'sum' function?

Comment: As per the data shown above you have same usernames and strengths in different rows while they have been defined as `primary key`

Comment: Have you tried this out on MemSQL 5? It includes [several](http://docs.memsql.com/v5.0/docs/release-notes) improvements to queries like this and was released soon after this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `sub aggregtaion` for that.

```
{
 "aggs": {
  "group by profile": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "userName",
        "order": {
           "intraday_return": "desc"
        }
      },
     "aggs": {
        "intraday_return": {
            "sum": {
          "script": "doc['strength'].value + doc['dexterity'].value"
       }
        }
     }
    }
  }
 }
```

Make sure [to enable scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: Is it possible to sum two fields from within the profile? I want to sum "strength" value with "dexterity" value, so that I can order by the combined sum. For example "sum : { field : strength, field: dexterity}" or something like that?

Comment: You have to use `scripting` for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Great, I will try this out - do you have any idea if scripting is less performant than "native" aggregations?

Comment: Yes scripting is less performant than native aggregation. Study http://code972.com/blog/2015/03/84-elasticsearch-one-tip-a-day-avoid-costly-scripts-at-all-costs

Comment: Works beautifully - query that was taking 240ms in MemSQL takes 44ms in Elasticsearch, even using scripting! Thanks for the help